# Changelog in Redmine

Tags: redmine

Hi
I'm using Redmine as a project management system. How would you keep a changelog of your projects between versions? Should I simply create a custom field for the issues? What about the changelog report?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just assign your issues to versions. All issues in a version will be listed (and hopefully closed) will be displayed when you go to the roadmap of your project.

If you want to add something manual to a version you can go to the project settings->versions->edit and add a wiki-page name (also create the actual wiki page if it does not exist).

That should suffice, no?

Comment: That lists the name of all issues. I don't want all my issues to have changelog text and definately not to use the names of the issues. Changelog text should be optional.

Comment: Thanks for your reply Stefan. Unfortunately it doesn't answer my question. I've seen other isses system that have optional text box for each issue that developers can fill in if they think the change they are doing should be on the changelog report for the version. I think I need to add an optinal field where issues are created and for each version manually fetch from the database this text for. I was just hoping there existed some plugin for this stuff.

Comment: So you basically want to have all "issue closed notes" collected as a changelog?

Comment: Well, more or less, but developers don't have the rights to close issues, only mark them as resolved. Managers close the issues. The developers, or the person creating the issues should write this text.
I think I'm just going to use the Milestone list, edit it and paste in into a Wiki page.

Comment: What I would prefer is that when you create an issue that is assigned to a version you have a checkbox that tell is if whats-new-text should be written for that issue. A text field also exists for entering the whats-new-text. If the checkbox is checked than the issues cannot be closed unless the whats-new-text has been written. That way you don't have to use the issue's title in the ChangeLog and can choose what isses appear on the changelog. .. .. But I guess that's not going to happend any soon :-)

Comment: Maybe it would be possible to bring in commit messages for the issues somehow, if you got your Redmine integrated with a CVS. But it'd need some kind of plugin.

Answer (score 4):

Seems there was a [redmine changelogs plugin](https://projects.littlestreamsoftware.com/projects/redmine-changelogs) but the link at [chiliproject.org](https://www.chiliproject.org/projects/chiliproject/wiki/Plugin_Compatibility) is 404 by now and I can't locate any fork either; maybe you'll be more successful.

Update: Redmine Changelogs is available [on GitHub](https://github.com/edavis10/redmine_changelogs).